# TFF and WOFF webfonts 404 not found

Tags: css, webfonts, woff

I am getting a 404 file not found on to webfont files when checking with Firebug.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Grotesk";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('../../themes/brian2013/css/fonts/grotesk/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.eot');
  src: local(Grotesk), url('../../themes/brian2013/css/fonts/grotesk/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"), url('../../themes/brian2013/css/fonts/grotesk/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.woff') format("woff"), url('../../themes/brian2013/css/fonts/grotesk/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.ttf') format("truetype"), url('../../themes/brian2013/css/fonts/grotesk/altehaasgroteskbold-webfont.svg#Grotesk') format("svg");
}
```

I have other fonts on this website which work perfectly. The EOT and SVG files work fine, I've checked the path on the other two and they correspond.

Answer (score 3):

Check your htaccess file to ensure you have the correct MIME types for the files.

**Example**

taken from [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

```
# Webfonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf         ttf ttc
AddType font/opentype                  otf
AddType application/x-font-woff        woff
```